# How to make many shapes quickly in tkinter

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to make shapes using Canvas in tkinter and it is going well. However I am trying to make an animation using random numbers that has boxes of different sizes moving around the screen. I was wondering what was the most Pythonic way of creating about 20 or 30 shapes and then being able to move them and change colour without creating each one a line of code and then referencing it later. I could then use this to have the shapes be different sizes using the `randint` function.

Many Thanks

Comment: You can create them in a loop if you don't want to create each one individually. Have you tried that?

Comment: I would need multiple shapes to be seen at the screen at once, so I can't think of a way that would work

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You can easily create thousands of canvas items in well under a second using a loop. I suggest you try.

Comment: I would need to have a way of moving the shapes around on the screen. My current method for this has been using the canvas.move which requires you to put it in a loop and then move it pixel by pixel. This works for one shape but the problem i have is using this process for multiple shapes

Comment: Creating them in a loop doesn't prevent you from moving them around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple items in a loop. Save the item ids in a list, and then you can iterate over the items to move them.

Here's an example that creates 100 items in random locations with random colors, and then animates them falling at random amounts each iteration.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black", width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

items = []
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randint(10, 490)
    y = random.randint(10, 490)
    size = random.randint(20,50)
    color = random.choice(("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "white", "yellow"))
    item_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+size, y+size, fill=color, outline="white")
    items.append(item_id)

def animate():
    for item_id in items:
        distance = random.randint(0, 5)
        canvas.move(item_id, 0, distance)
    canvas.after(100, animate)

animate()
root.mainloop()
```

Here's an object-oriented approach where we use a class to define an item, and the class instance can animate itself.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class RandomItem:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.velocity = random.randint(1,5)
        x = random.randint(10, 490)
        y = random.randint(10, 490)
        size = random.randint(20,50)
        color = random.choice(("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "white", "yellow"))
        self.item_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+size, y+size, fill=color)
        self.fall()

    def fall(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.item_id, 0, self.velocity)
        self.canvas.after(100, self.fall)


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(100):
    item = RandomItem(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```